# Move data from an external system into Teradata database

Tags: odata, etl, teradata, sap-erp, sap-gateway

I have exposed a set of data as OData service from SAP ERP via Gateway. I get the data in the form of xml/json. I would like to access the XML/JSON data and update it onto a table in the Teradata database.

How to consume XML data on Teradata?
or
Which is the best way to transport data from SAP to Teradata?

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a one-time data load or should it be an ongoing process?
[This blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/05/the-various-data-provisioning-options-for-hana/) will probably get you started searching in a more specific direction. Do note that there will be non-SAP products capable of this task as well.